# TextMate Theme Select Attribute Value

Tags: textmate

I need to change the color of certain attributes/tags. I am switching from Dreamweaver and making the skin has been really hard in TextMate.

[image: Dreamweaver and TextMate comparison]

As you can see, I want to change the a and img tags along with all of their attributes. The closest I've come to find is `entity.other.attribute-name` which only works with id for some reason `entity.other.attribute-name.id`

Bonus would be the scope selector for the value of an attribute, e.g. "Logo" alt in the above example.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

TextMate's Bundle Development Plugin has a Show Scope and Copy Scope. Put your text cursor in say the middle of the area you want colored, then trigger one of those: does that narrow down the selector for you?

(Maybe that's how you got the selectors you mentioned in the first place, but thought I'd mention it...)

Comment: Copy Scope! Thanks, that helps a lot but I've found this and it seems to be a good reference: http://forums.mactalk.com.au/20/42236-textmate-bundle-editing-syntax-highlighting.html